# How to start flask server with docker run and use it on host?

Tags: python, flask, docker

I have a flask script which I try to execute it via docker run command. Following command i am doing

```
docker run -dit -v /media/sf_MY_WINDOWS/GitRepo/:/ext/GitRepo -p 5000:5000 "isbhatt/prefixman:v1" /ext/docker/vm_scripts/db_loader.sh
```

and db_loader.sh file contains

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /ext/SDSNG/src/prefix_manager/manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0 &
```

but when I do curl localhost:5000 Connection refused.
If I go into container and run the stuff and do curl localhost:5000 it works in container..
What is wrong here?

Output of netstat -tln on container

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to deploy your app in Docker without having to learn, install and configure uWSGI, Nginx and Supervisord (to get the best performance and robustness), you may want to check this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inside your container your script is binding to `127.0.0.1`, then the port forwarding normally provided using `-p` will not work.  Ensure that inside the container your service is listening on `0.0.0.0`.

You can check on what address your service is listening by running `netstat -tln` inside the container:

```
container# netstat -tln
```

If you see this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Then that's your problem.  You want to see:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: @Iarsks You are right I can see 127.0.0.1:5000. What should I do to overcome it?

Comment: According to [these docs](https://flask-runner.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you probably need to add `--host 0.0.0.0` to your `runserver` command.

Comment: @Iarsks Nope, In container I am able to do it, but from docker run I am still unable to connect on 5000 port.

Comment: Can you update your question to show (a) your modified `db_loader.sh` with the `--host` argument, and (b) the output of `netstat -tln` inside the container after it starts?

Comment: @Isrsks See the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. By removing & at the end of manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0 
That & kept the process in the background and if no process is running in foreground the container would stop even if you have provided -d option.
And @Iarsks , Yup  the --host has to be 0.0.0.0 .